# "Reverse" Chebyshev Inequality that gives lower bound of being far from mean

Tags: probability, variance, binomial-distribution

Chebyshev's inequality gives an *upper* bound on $P(|X - \mu| \geq k\sigma)$ but I was wondering if there was a way to find a *lower* bound for this probability or, equivalently an upper bound on $P(|X - \mu| < k\sigma)$.

What about with added assumptions? For example, is there any way to get a lower bound for the probability that a $\textrm{Binomial}(n, p)$ variable takes a value more than a constant $K$ away from the mean?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question: no there isn't. Consider a random variable $X$ taking values $\pm n$ each with probability $\frac{1}{2n^2}$ and $0$ otherwise. This has $\mathbb E(X)=0$ and $\mathbb E(X^2)=1$, but for fixed $k$ the probability $\mathbb P(|X|>k)=\frac 1{n^2}$ can be made arbitrarily small by choosing $n>k$ appropriately.

However, in this example the third moment $\mathbb E(X^3)=n$ goes to infinity. It turns out this is a necessary feature of such an example: you can get a lower bound for the tail probability in terms of the mean and second and third moments. See [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/reader/236623940) by Rohatgi and Székely. This will give something nontrivial for e.g. binomial distributions.